# Unable to use tf.while_loop properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My code :

```
def entropy(x):
  return tf.convert_to_tensor(skimage.measure_shannon_entropy(np.array(x)))
```

```
def calc_entropy(x, fn):
  i = tf.constant(0)
  while_condition = lambda i: tf.less(i, fn)
  #loop
  r = tf.while_loop(while_condition, entropy, x[0, :, :, i])
  return r
```

```
a = tf.constant([[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]]) # shape=(1, 2, 2, 2)
output = calc_entropy(a, 2)
```

Output : [1.23, 0.12]

But my code is showing this error :
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage.measure.entropy import shannon_entropy
import numpy as np

def entropy(i, v, x):
  v = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(v, [[i]], [tf.convert_to_tensor(shannon_entropy(np.array(x[0, :, :, i])))])
  return tf.add(i, 1), v, x

def calc_entropy(x, fn):
  i = tf.constant(0)
  v = tf.zeros((fn,), dtype=tf.float64)
  while_condition = lambda i, v, x: tf.less(i, fn)
  _, v, _ = tf.while_loop(while_condition, entropy, loop_vars=(i, v, x))
  return v 

a = tf.constant([[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]])
output = calc_entropy(a, 2)
print(output)
```

```
tf.Tensor([2. 2.], shape=(2,), dtype=float64)
```

However, I do not know how you expect the output `[1.23, 0.12]`. Check the calculations manually:

```
a = np.array([[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]])
print(shannon_entropy(a[0, :, :, 0]))
print(shannon_entropy(a[0, :, :, 1]))
```

```
2.0
2.0
```

Comment: sorry for the output. I randomly guessed it to clear the output size.